# Film where the government was corrupt with aliens, people sent to kill aliens are given rigged visors not showing the right targets

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember a film where the government was corrupt with aliens, people were sent out to kill these said aliens with visors which would show an alien if there was a green heart present, however these visors were rigged and were the opposite.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202076/science-fiction-book-series-about-aliens-that-look-exactly-like-humans-protagon (about the novel on which the film was based)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*The 5th Wave* (2016)?

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2304933/):

> When Earth is attacked by aliens, there is a sequence of waves of destruction to annihilate the population. The aliens drain the energy and create diseases and natural disasters. The teenager Cassie Sullivan moves with her family to the countryside, but when her mother Lisa dies, her father Oliver decides to go to a refugee camp with Cassie and her young brother Sam. Out of the blue, the army comes to the camp to transfer the survivors to a military base. They transfer the children first but Cassie misses the bus where Sam is. **She learns that the in the 5th wave, the aliens have assumed the human form and she witnesses the military executing the civilians in the camp including her father.** She flees and now she begins her quest to find Sam. **Meanwhile the teenagers and children are trained by the military to fight the enemy. But how to know who is human and who is alien?**

At some point, the kids under military training are given visors that *supposedly* show the "aliens", with a green thingy in their brain (which looks like an insect, not a heart). It's revealed that

> the visors are rigged so that the *humans* show up as aliens, meaning the kids are the new "wave" of human extermination.

Scene is pictured below:

Comment: A similar concept has been used in `BlackMirror` episode [`Man Against Fire`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_Against_Fire).